# Can I make a directory in launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My local machine is a laptop running Ubuntu 10.04 (old, I know).  While collecting data during my experiments, I am generating text files for Matlab, but I want to organize a single experiment into a new directory. Here is my test code (found on an ANT reference page):

```
<!-- -*- mode: XML -*-  -->
<launch>
  <mkdir dir="/home/turtlebot/00x/"/>
  <!-- Other Stuff excluded as irrelevant -->
</launch>
```

Does anyone know a way to have a directory (in this case /00x/) automatically generated using XML?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150286/can-i-make-a-directory-in-launch-file?/) by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-04-14**:
I made a shell script and called it this way:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also, nodes can be shell scripts, making directory creation pretty straightforward.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-04-14**:
I made a shell script and called it this way:

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot do this directly in your launch file.

If you have a node that requires a directory to exist, you can have that node create the directory in question.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-04-08**:
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this interesting hack in [maxwell_calibration](https://github.com/mikeferguson/maxwell/blob/sixdof/maxwell_calibration/capture_data/capture_exec.launch):

```
  <node type="record" pkg="rosbag" name="robot_measurement_recorder" output="screen"
        args="-O /tmp/maxwell_calibration/cal_measurements robot_measurement robot_description" >
    <!-- Hack to create the directory -->
    <param name="mkdir_tmp" command="mkdir -m 777 -p /tmp/maxwell_calibration" />
  </node>
```

So it appears you can create folders from launch files (using very hacky abuse of parameters)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
This method is interesting!